# Jquery Ajax only Works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that is reloading the data in a div, I am using jquery to update the div, but it only fires once.

My page looks like this:

```
<html><head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><body>
<div id="messages" style="width:100%;font-size:120%;">
  <?php echo $tbl; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#messages').load ('new_hud.php?update=true');
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

I am expecting the script to load the data every 2 seconds.  It initialy reloads the data after the first 2 seconds, but then never does again.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setInterval rather than setTimeout.

setTimeout will fire once after a specified delay.

setInterval will fire repeatedly with the specified interval.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var updater = setInterval(function () {
        $('div#messages').load('new_hud.php?update=true');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and well explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `setTimeout` with `setInterval`, like so

```
var updater = setInterval(function () {
    $('div#messages').load ('new_hud.php?update=true');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and want to use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

```
var updater = setInterval (function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout function by itself won't cycle your script every 2 seconds so what your code is doing is basically waiting 2 after the page is ready to load the data and that's it.

Wrap the setTimeout in a 'for' or 'while' cycle to load the number of times you want.

Hope it's useful :)

Comment: This would create a vast number of timeouts immediately on page load? You could chain the timeouts such that the callback creates a new timeout but you should not create them with a for loop.